# Chrome's Treatment of Height / Min-height

Tags: html, google-chrome, layout, css

It seems that Chrome recently changed how it handles `height` and `min-height`. Previously setting `min-height` on an element was analogous to setting `height` in that any child elements could use percentage heights based on the parent height. It seems that this is no longer the case, and that only an explicit height as opposed to an explicit `min-height` is good enough to given a child element a context in which it can use percentage heights.

So setting `height: 100%` on the `html` element and `body` element now causes them to become fixed at the height of the initial viewport.

**How can the body element be made to extend to the height of its content while still supplying a percentage-height context for child elements?**

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an example of the problem you are seeing?

Percentage heights have never been based on min-height; they have only been based on a parent that has a known height (not content height and not min-height). That means the parent must either have a fixed pixel height or that the parent has a percentage height based on another parent where the height can be resolved.

The usual fix is to set html and body to height:100% and then the page wrapper to min-height:100%. Although the html and body are fixed to 100% this will not be an issue as the wrapper simply overflows (unless you are adding different background to html and body which is not generally recommended).

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:blue;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    max-width:1150px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#f9f9f9;
    padding:10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are seeing something different or if you have a different set up then we will need to see an example :)

(Of course for modern browsers we can use the vh unit to make elements extend to the bottom of the viewport.)

Comment: Does Chrome have other issues with html, body that I'm not aware of? Otherwise, AFAIK the behavior of html, body in terms of CSS is very well-defined, and is consistent across all browsers dating back to IE8. I consider setting different backgrounds on html and body a viable alternative to CSS3 layered backgrounds for as long as legacy browsers remain relevant (which admittedly isn't much longer now, but it's a technique I've used for years).

Comment: The problem with using html for background is when using html and body at 100% and the body background will stop at the bottom of the viewport while content overflows. The html background will continue underneath though. When you apply a background to the body only then it is automatically propagated to the html element. If you are not using html and body at height:100% then it is ok to use both html and body as backgrounds but remembering that body is now only as tall as its content (there are ways around this of course).

Answer (score 0):

In my snippet below, I set 100% height on `html` and `body`, yet the content is based on the `body` min-height rather than the viewport height.  As you add more content, `body` expands as you'll see with the yellow margin.  This seems to contradict your statement, but perhaps we're using different versions of Chrome:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 1000px;
  background: yellow;
}

div {
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #def;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem</div>
<div>Ipsum</div>
<div>Dolor</div>
<div>Marco</div>
<div>Polo</div>
```